# How to write cratedb migration scripts ? Migration Scripts not working

Tags: sql, cratedb

we have a database which has a table called Students with columns id,name,age,school.

Now i want to write a migration script to copy 3 columns (lets assume i have millions of records) from Students table to New_students table .

Below is my sample script which i have written . It is throwing an error

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS New_Students (
id PRIMARY KEY,
name string,
age string,
)

INSERT INTO New_Students(id,name,age)
SELECT  id,name,age
FROM students;
```

When executed above in crateDb Admin UI, i get below error

```
SQLActionException[SQLParseException: line 8:1: mismatched input 'INSERT' expecting <EOF>]
```

The above statements works when executing individually .

Question:

1. Why is above multiple statements are not working , but it works when typed individually ?
   2.How to do we copy data from table columns to another new table . Let us say i have millions of records , how do i do it more efficiently ?

Comment: Perhaps you need a `;` between the statements?

Comment: I did that and still the same error .

Comment: Remove the `,` just before `)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL console of the CrateDB AdminUI does not support multiple statements.

You could use the `crash` CLI tool instead, which does support multiple statements, see https://crate.io/docs/clients/crash/en/latest/.

Answer (score 0):

put a semicolon after create table statement

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS New_Students (
id int PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(100),
age varchar(100) -- you need to remove this line coma as well 
);

INSERT INTO New_Students(id,name,age)
SELECT  id,name,age
FROM students;
```

Comment: @RakeshSrinivasa did you use proper data type in times of table creation i just seen you also need some correction in table create sql check now i edited

Answer (score 0):

1. There's only 1 statement during a single request as you say it works when you separate the queries, so you do need to do two statements.
2. Even with million of records it's still a single statements so shouldn't matter on efficiency? You're only running 1 more separate script to create a new table the insert will work as expected taking however long it might.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create the table directly from the data?

```
CREATE TABLE New_Students as
    SELECT id, name, age
    FROM students;
```

Your problem is the interface that only allows you to send on statement at a time.  In this case, though, you may not need two statements.